# Count a range, then color it

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I'm trying to run a simple script to count a range and color it, but I'm getting a 1004 error.

The range-count works and displays the counted range fine.

```
Sub text()
    Dim t As Integer
    t = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "*")
    Dim textstringA As String
    textstringA = "A2:A" & t
    Range("J1") = textstringA

    'Coloring the counted range does not work. Only 1 active sheet exists in the book. 
    'I've tried several other similar methods shown in the forum, but I keep getting 
    'errors on the same line. I tried using 'select' as well before coloring, but no 
    'good. 

    Dim rngA As Range
    Set rngA = ActiveSheet.Range("textstringA")    `debug_error_here`
    Range("textrangeA").Interior.ColorIndex = 10 
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please add all the tags that are relevant to your question; here, especially the language you're using is missing.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the quotes from `textstringA` wherever you are trying to use its value...

```
Set rngA = ActiveSheet.Range(textstringA)
Range(textrangeA).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
```

You aren't defining `textrangeA` anywhere.
Next, this will fail if `t` < 2. So you need to account for such an eventuality.

Try

```
    Range(textstringA).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
```

and you will see that it works.